# Understanding an example

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $T= \{ W' \subseteq W : W' \text{ is a subspace of } V \text{ containing } A\}$.
 Then $T \neq \emptyset$ as $W \in T$. Thus $\bigcap T$ exists.

My question is that why $W \in T$ and $\bigcap T$ exists?

Comment: @par this intersection $W'$.

Comment: What are $V$, $A$ and $W$?

Comment: @David Let V be a vector space over F and let A ⊆ V be a subset. Then there is a subspace W of V such that

     i) A ⊆ W

      ii) If W′ is a subspace of V containing A, then W ⊆ W

Comment: $F$ is a field, I suppose. I still don't understand what $W$ is. Are you trying to prove that a subspace $W$ satisfying certain conditions exists? Or is the fact that $W$ satisfies those conditions an assumption of the problem? I don't think $W \subseteq W$ is what you meant, either.

Comment: @David Proposition is from lecture notes. There is a wrong, isn't there? T doesn't be as T = { W′ ⊆ W : W′ is a subspace of V containing A}. Firstly, it should be T = { W ⊆ W' ... .

Comment: Is this proposition to prove the existence of a smallest subspace containing $A$?

Comment: @David Secondly, I did not these W $\in$ T and ∩T exists (why exist) (why W $\in$ T )

Comment: @David Yes, it is.

Comment: @David There's something about it i don't get.  What is the T as illustration? What is the ∩T? Why W  is an intersection of subspaces? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think was meant. I think the letter $W$ was sometimes written/copied erroneously in place of $V$.

**Proposition** Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, and let $A$ be a subset of $V$. Then there exists a subspace $W$ of $V$ with the following properties:

(i) $A \subseteq W$; and

(ii) if $W'$ is any subspace of $V$ such that $A \subseteq W'$, then $W \subseteq W'$.

**Proof**

Let $T = \{W' \subseteq V \mid \text{$W'$ is a subspace containing $A$}\}$. We have $T \ne \varnothing$ because $V \in T$.

Write $W = \cap T$, which exists since $T \ne \varnothing$. Since $W$ is an intersection of subspaces, $W$ is itself a subspace. Since all these subspaces contain $A$, the subspace $W$ itself contains $A$, proving (i).

Moreover if $W'$ is any subspace containing $A$, we have $W' \in T$, hence $W'$ is one of the subspaces appearing in the intersection defining $W$. Therefore $W \subseteq W'$, which proves (ii).

Comment: There's something about it i don't get. What is the T as illustration? What is the ∩T? Why W is an intersection of subspaces? Can you explain?

Comment: $W = \cap T$ (also written $\cap_{W' \in T} W'$) is the set of all $x$ such that $x \in W'$ for every $W' \in T$. By definition, $W$ is the intersection of all the subspaces belonging to $T$.